# integral with trig substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Problem:

Integrate : $\displaystyle \int^\pi_0\hspace{1mm}\sin^2t\cos^4t~dt$

What I tried :

1. Use the pythagorean identity $\cos^2t=1-\sin^2t$ to rewrite the problem as $$\int^\pi_0\hspace{1mm}\sin^2t\hspace{1mm}(1-\sin^2t)\cos^2t\,dt$$
2. Distribute $\sin^2t$ to rewrite the problem as

   $$\int^\pi_0\hspace{1mm}(\sin^2t-\sin^4t)\cos^2t \, dt$$
3. let $u = \sin^2t$ ; $du=2\cos^2t\hspace{1mm}dt$
4. Make the u substitution to rewrite the problem as

   $$\frac 1 2 \int^{\sin^2\pi}_{\sin^20}\hspace{1mm}u - u^2\,du$$

When evaluated the whole thing obviously just goes to zero. When I look in the back of the book the correct answer is $\hspace{2mm}\pi/16$

Comment: You substituted $u = \sin^2 t$. So $du = 2 \sin t \cos t \ dt$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:)** Use identities
$$\sin^2t=\dfrac{1-\cos2t}{2}~~~~,~~~~\cos^2t=\dfrac{1+\cos2t}{2}$$
and reduce powers.

Comment: I have qualms about the use of the word "hint" for this sort of thing.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I can delete this qualms thing if you want!

Comment: @MyGlasses Thanks, That does get me toward the right answer, but where did I go wrong in the substitution I made?

Comment: @MyGlasses Nevermind I borked the derivative. THANKS

Comment: You made a mistake in $du$ as @samjoe said in his comments, anyway this substitution isn't applicable since it need a term of $cos$ with power $1$ only.

Comment: @richbai90 Your welcome, Sure that you can finish your problem!